# React only run tailwindcss when I run npm start

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I use tailwindcss for my react app. But when I add className to React element, the program restart but there is no css attribute to my element (even when I see in inspect on developer tool).
I don't know why. I install through https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/create-react-app link

Comment: Hi Millie, Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). People who are interested will help you. You need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to ease the process of providing a solution

Comment: Please include the steps you have taken in intializing the application, your code sample and the output on the dom

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.